# perl strftime localtime minus 12 hours

Tags: perl, datetime, strftime, localtime

I im using perl strftime for (datetime now)

```
perl -MPOSIX -e 'print POSIX::strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M", localtime());'
```

i want to minus  datetime now by 12 hour

Example OUTPUT:
`2/7/2020 1:00` to `2/6/2020 13:00` <- minus 12 hours only

Please help to solve this problem by using mentioned code

Answer (score 5):

The [POSIX](https://perldoc.perl.org/POSIX.html)'s `strftime`

> Returns the string.

and you can't conveniently subtract hours from a string.<sup>†</sup>

Instead, use a library for date-time processing for manipulation, and then format with `strftime`

An example with [Time::Piece](https://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html)

```
perl -MTime::Piece -MTime::Seconds -wE'
    $t = (localtime) - 12*ONE_HOUR;
    say $t->strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")'
```

The [Time::Seconds](https://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Seconds.html) comes along with `Time::Piece`, for various datetime computations.

While `Time::Piece` is core and good and well known it does come with subtleties and limitations, and for more involved work I'd recommend the all-knowing (and big and heavy) [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime)

```
perl -MDateTime -wE'
    $t = DateTime->now(time_zone => "local")->subtract(hours => 12); 
    say $t->strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")'
```

I think it's worth emphasizing that this module can do practically everything with datetimes.

---

As a note, keep in mind the issues that Daylight-Saving Time changes bring. Between miraculous jumps of the clock and occasional non-existing hours there may be unpleasant surprises, albeit rarely ([an example](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime#Invalid-Local-Times)).

Here is a program [provided](https://pastebin.com/CckCS3Mw) by [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami) to test for the [coming DST](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/usa/new-york?year=2020) (Mar 08, 2am -> 3am)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime      qw( );
use POSIX         qw( strftime );
use Time::Piece   qw( localtime );
use Time::Seconds qw( ONE_HOUR );

my $epoch = 1583683200;  # 2020-03-08T12:00:00

CORE::say
   for
      DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => $epoch, time_zone => $ENV{TZ} )
              ->subtract( hours => 12 ),
      strftime("%FT%T", localtime($epoch - 12*60*60)),
      ( localtime($epoch) - 12*ONE_HOUR )->strftime("%FT%T");
```

Then set `TZ` environment variable and run it

```
TZ=America/New_York perl test_DST.pl
```

(in bash, while in tcsh it's `setenv TZ "America/New_York"; perl test_DST.pl`)

The output

```
2020-03-07T23:00:00
2020-03-07T23:00:00
2020-03-07T23:00:00
```

---

<sup>†</sup> A function with that name exists in many environments and  always returns a formatted string.

Comment: @ikegami Ah, great!  Interesting that all (three methods shown on this page -- `localtime` tweak and two in this answer) "work" the same.   I don't understand though how it winds up (down, rather) at 11pm...  (I think it'd be a good idea to include that code of yours in this answer)

Comment: America/New_York uses EDT for the start ts, but EST for the earlier ts. 12 hours before noon EDT is midnight EDT or 11pm EST.

Comment: @ikegami ugh, right. thank you. i've added your program to the post

Answer (score 1):

Using [Time::Moment](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment) and [Time::Moment::Role::TimeZone](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Moment::Role::TimeZone) (to correct for DST changes):

```
perl -MTime::Moment -MWith::Roles -E'say Time::Moment->with::roles("+TimeZone")->now
  ->minus_hours(12)->with_system_offset_same_instant->strftime("%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")'
```